# Теоретический вопрос

Tags: сетевое-программирование

Нужно соединить двух клиентов под NAT напрямую. Одна проблема — обратиться к ним напрямую нельзя. Но: когда хост подключается к серверу, роутер его сети создаёт соответствие локального ip и порта с портом самого роутера, и когда сервер присылает ответ, то он редиректится на соответствующий хост, а соответствие удаляется. Тогда появляется идея: отправить запрос через роутер, чтобы он создал соответствие, а ответ на нужный порт прислать с другого компьютера, к которому надо подключиться. Такой "нелегальный" проброс портов. Вопрос в том, что:
1) можно ли отправить запрос на подключение и ждать достаточно долго, чтобы другой клиент успел подменить ответ сервера;
2) всегда ли роутер ставит в соответствие для порта локального хоста один и тот же собственный порт?

Comment: Именно так и работает STUN. Но работает это не для всех видов NAT

Comment: И кстати если под «запросом на подключение» вы подразумеваете TCP-соединение, то обойти NAT для TCP невозможно, можно только для UDP

Comment: @andreymal можно ли отправить запрос самому себе таким образом, а ответ прислать от машины к которой нужно подключиться? Чтобы не использовать сервера

Comment: Без сервера нельзя, кто-то извне должен сообщить внешние IP и порт, а кроме сервера больше в общем-то и некому

Comment: @andreymal А если отправить самому себе, вытащить внешние ip и порт и передать их человеку с которым нужно соединиться, чтобы он прислал ответ на этот порт?

Comment: Самому себе через внешнюю сеть не получится